# Use String Row As column

Tags: sql-server

I have UserExams tables shown below 
I need to display like `FirstName, First, Second, Final`

I've tried using PIVOT but the aggregation function don't return all StudentMarks

```
select *
from
(
SELECT     Users.FirstName,
           ExamsNames.Name,
           UserExams.StudentMark
FROM         Exams INNER JOIN ExamsNames ON Exams.ExamNameID = ExamsNames.ExamsNamesID 
                   INNER JOIN UserExams ON Exams.ExamID = UserExams.ExamID 
                   INNER JOIN Users ON UserExams.UserID = Users.UserID 
)t
PIVOT
(
min(StudentMark)
for  Name in ([First],[Second],[Final])
)p
```

[image: data from userexams table]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way your current query is written you are going to return one `min(StudentMark)` for each exam in `Name`.  If you want to return multiple values for each exam, then you will want to include another column that will give you distinct rows - I would suggest using `row_number`:

```
select FirstName, [First],[Second],[Final]
from
(
  SELECT Users.FirstName,
    ExamsNames.Name,
    UserExams.StudentMark,
    row_number() over(partition by Users.FirstName, ExamsNames.Name
                      order by UserExams.StudentMark) seq
  FROM Exams 
  INNER JOIN ExamsNames ON Exams.ExamNameID = ExamsNames.ExamsNamesID 
  INNER JOIN UserExams ON Exams.ExamID = UserExams.ExamID 
  INNER JOIN Users ON UserExams.UserID = Users.UserID 
)t
PIVOT
(
  min(StudentMark)
  for  Name in ([First],[Second],[Final])
)p
```